# Get the minimum value and its index with a for loop

Tags: java, loops, double

How can I get the minimum value in a for loop plus its index:?

**Update:**  This is what I tried after using @Sakalya 's answer

```
      LatLng myLatLang = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(),myLocation.getLongitude());

        double minval = -1.0;
        int minIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < stationsCoord.size(); i++) {

            double distance = CalculationByDistance(myLatLang,stationsCoord.get(i));

            if(distance < minval){
                minval = distance;
                minIndex = i;
            }

            Log.i("distance " , String.valueOf(distance));

            System.out.println("min=" +minval+ "index="+minIndex);

        }

      //i'm looking for the min value of 'distance' + the index 'i'
```

I always get this: `System.out: min=-1.0index=0`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can set a min variable to 1000000 and then iterate the list to find min value as below:

```
LatLng myLatLang = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());

double minval = 1000000000000.0;
int minIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < stationsCoord.size(); i++) {

    double distance = CalculationByDistance(myLatLang,stationsCoord.get(i));

    if (distance < minval) {
      minval = distance;
      minIndex = i;
    }

    Log.i("distance " , String.valueOf(distance));

    System.out.println("min=" +minval+ "index="+minIndex);

}
```

Comment: As a general tip, it is best to not set a minvalue to -1 but rather to a value in the array or list you are using. Without doing this, your code will break for any value of distance greater than -1.

Comment: i got" System.out: min=-1.0index=0"

Answer (score 1):

In the following code

```
double minval = -1.0;
if (somepositivedistance < minval ) { // do something
}
```

nothing will ever return true if the distance is positive, therefore the statement will never execute.

You need to set `minval`to something greater then the largest possible distance (for example `Double.MAX_VALUE`) before entering the for-loop.

> 